# Why is Pycharm showing socket.io errors when starting a project that doesn't use sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, pycharm

I'm having an issue with a project showing these socket errors like it's still trying to connect `127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2021 10:12:12] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NfOK-g6 HTTP/1.1" 404 -` when I try to start/debug the project. Now this project doesn't use any sockets, but another project in Pycharm I was using earlier did use sockets. It's like theres something cached or something left over affecting other projects once I'm done with the project that does use sockets. I've cleared the cache and restarting the laptop seems to fix it, only I don't want to be constantly restarting my laptop to get rid of the errors. Anyone ever have to deal with/fix this before? If so how did you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a chrome tab that still had the other project running I had separated from the other chrome tabs. That tab even being open was causing this issue. Closed the tab and fixed it.